# Add FontAwesome 4 in vue using vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, font-awesome

I'm using vuetify, and I need to add font awesome library, but I don't know how to do it, it looks like the vuetify documentation is not updated, the guide for add font awesome says I should add the next in main.js:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
 iconfont: 'fa4'
})
```

or something similar,my problem is that I'm using another method for run the app, my main.ts is the next:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
require('@/SCSS/main.scss')

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

If I add the "Iconfont" to my New Vue({}),it doesn't work.

how can I add font awesome to vuetify in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use vue-fontawesome.
First install fontawesome vue-fontawesome, core and icons:

```
$ npm i @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
$ npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

Then in `src/main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faUserSecret)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Now that it is done you will be able to use the icons using the next tag:

```
<font-awesome-icon icon="user-secret" />
```

All you have to do is replace the value in the icon attribute:
`icon="Replace this text"`

EDIT 1: Here you have a working example in codesandbox:

[image: Edit broken-feather-y3kzs]

EDIT 2:
I will add a screenshot because CodeSanbox sometimes takes a lot of time to load, this is just to prove that if you wait you can actually see the icon.
[image]

Comment: It says doesn't found '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome', I already install the libraries, also without import it, the project doesn't runs, I'm using typescript

Comment: Did you try with my code? It is working as you can see in the example I added. And also, where is the error coming from? Is it from the command line, the console, where?